# OpenGraph not working

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I made an action "criar" and an object "oferta" on my app. The code it came back for creating an page was:

```
<head prefix="og: xttp://ogp.me/ns# fb: xttp://ogp.me/ns/fb# testegraph: xttp://ogp.me/ns/fb/testegraph#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="186721904779529" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="testegraph:oferta" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://www.vendefacil.net:7979/mkt21manager/Welcome.jsf" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Oferta" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```

(i placed the metas with \ instead of < so they could be read)

I tried a direct post to OpenGraph with the following url:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/testegraph:criar?oferta=http://www.vendefacil.net:7979/mkt21manager/OpenGraph/oferta.html&access_token="+vc.getAccesstoken();
```

The result is:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request [Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, Cache-Control: no-store, Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8, Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT, Pragma: no-cache, WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#3502) Object at URL http://www.vendefacil.net:7979/mkt21manager/OpenGraph/oferta.html has og:type of 'website'. The property 'oferta' requires an object of og:type 'testegraph:oferta'. ", X-FB-Rev: 644018, X-FB-Debug: Kvtoba9EGskocz2wxI7T2iXvfzV8SvjdxNNzuYfSCp8=, Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2012 16:33:15 GMT, Connection: keep-alive, Content-Length: 252]
```

Seems to be complaining about the provided website not have testegraph:oferta as og:type and i know that is in the given website. So what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)  your app sends an immediate 302 redirect to 
`302 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=153701288088609&redirect_uri=http://www.vendefacil.net:7979/mkt21manager/Welcome.jsf&scope=email,user_photos,user_location,user_groups,status_update&response_type=code`

The crawler follows the redirect, but won't scrape facebook.com URLs so the information about your page can't be updated.

You need to exempt Facebook's crawler from the redirect and serve the correct meta tags

Comment: Ok I saw the problem and tried using a simple website such as "http://www.google.com" instead of "http://www.vendefacil.net:7979/mkt21manager/Welcome.jsf". Still got warnings on debug:   Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: Yes, Google.com doesn't have the open graph meta tags either.
You need your URL to serve correct tags to the facebook crawler.

Comment: I solved the page and now it works fine on Debug. Problem is I cant use my Debug App to debug this program, going to test it directly on the release version because it wont look for the page on my localhost. Anyway i am going to test it in just a minute to see if the correct page still keeps the same error...